# Can I lua sort a table that has a column created by "row_number()" function in postgresql?

Tags: sorting, lua, postgresql-9.2, lua-table

I have a select statement that includes a call to the row_number() function, which technically gives me a unique id per row that is returned.

```sql
SELECT f.*, row_number() as row_id OVER(ORDER BY f.name)
FROM widgets f
```

It'd be kinda cool if i could somehow use this row_id to sort the table.  I'd now like to try to use the row_number to sort like so:

table.sort(mytable, function(a,b) return a.row_id< b.row_id end)

I'm just trying to save myself from having to loop through the results to add a unique id and then sort it but maybe it's not possible.

Comment: Why not simple `select ... order by f.name` and read result set consequentially?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would express this in Lua, but in Postgres you can order by a column alias.  The Postgres query would be:

```
SELECT f.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY f.name) as row_id
FROM widgets f
ORDER BY row_id;
```

The fact that you don't want to order by `f.name` suggests that you have duplicates.  Do note that ordering in SQL is not guaranteed to be stable.  That is, duplicate names could be in different orders.  If you have a way of making the ordering stable (i.e. by uniquely identifying each row), you can use those columns in the `order by`.